# Stack related questions with examples

Tags: c, stack

I have some questions about stack appearance while calling functions, and I have some small examples that will help explain my confusion: 
1)
Let's say we have these two functions

```
int h(int k){
   k = k+3;
   return k;


int f(int x, int y){ 
   int q; 
   int z = 10; //Checkpoint_1
   q = h(x); // Checkpoint_2
   return z;
```

**First question**: 
how will the stack look like after we reach the line of the Checkpoint_1, will the stack have the all the local variables (x,y,q,z)? how would they look like inside the stack? 

**Second question**: 
How will the stack look like after we reach checkpoint_2 and enter the function h(x) and put x+3 in q, will q change to x+3 in the stack frame? or will it stay the same q (having x+3 as value)?

**Third question:** 
What registers will these two functions use? I know that there's a register that will have the return value for each function in each frame in the stack (I think it's called %eax), but my confusion is, let's say in function h(int k), will %eax have value of k or k+3, or say in function f(int x, int y) will %eax have z or 10. 

I would really appreciate any help and tips regarding my questions.

Comment: Google `Application Binary Interface` (ABI), which has details like this, and they differ between platforms (OS/CPU/etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying that the compiler is free to do whatever it wants in some capacity - but all modern compilers are going to do it very similarly. I'm also going to assume we're talking about x86-64, utilizing the cdecl standard that's common on linux. It's different for 32-bit, and it's different for Windows.

Modern compilers usually allocate all space for stack variables at the beginning of the function call, regardless of scope. Usually this is done simply by *decreasing* the value in rsp. The stack grows down, which means *decreasing* the value is the same as *growing* the stack, hence, an allocation. In this case, you have two 4 byte values initialized on the stack, so the stack will have 8 bytes allocated on it. The two variables x and y will be stored in %rdi and %rsi respectively on 64-bit. (on 32-bit, they're stored above the return address on the stack.)

After the call to h(x), yes, the value of q in memory will change to (x+3).

The compiler will use whatever registers it feels like using. In this case, it's actually very likely for **everything** to be in registers, and for the stack to not be used at all except for the return address for h. When function h returns, the value of k (which is now k+3) will be stored in %eax and returned. When function f returns, the value in z will be stored in %eax and returned. Registers have no concept of variable names (like z), they simply have values. It is the responsibility of compilers to give those values meaning by associating that register with the concept of z.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just realized that you said that the variables, x and y are above the return address on the stack, does that mean it's outside of the function frame? what will happen as we dive deeper in the function when we call h(x) lets say, would x be pushed in the stack in the frame of function f? I'm a little bit confused about these stuff